# PersistenceContext propagation

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm migrating an application from desktop to web. In the desktop application, users connect to an Oracle database using different database users, ie users are managed by Oracle, not within a database table. All use the same scheme to store and manage data, PLMU_PROD.

I have to implement authentication (JPA) for the Web application and, as I read, I have to create a EntityManagerFactory for each database user.

The other option I'm thinking is to create a table of users / passwords and use the same EntityManagerFactory to serve all EntityManager, as all users will access the same data that is in the scheme PLMU_PROD.

I wonder if the PersistenceContext is shared between different EntityManagerFactories, as my web server has little RAM and do not want to waste it having duplicate entities.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to be referring to is caching.  JPA requires that EntityManagers keep entities cached so that they can track changes.  So each EntityManager is required to have its own cache, keeping changes made in one separate from changes that might be made concurrently in others - transaction isolation.  Within EclipseLink, there is a concept of a second level cache that is shared at the EMFactory level.  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching  is a good document on caching in EclipseLink. This second level cache helps avoid database access and can be disabled as required.  If your EntityManagers do not need to track changes, such as if the application is read-only and the entitys are not modified, you can set queries to return entities from the shared cache so that only a single instance of the data exists using the read-only query hint: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/q_read_only.htm#readonly

Read-only instances can allow avoiding duplication and using resources unnecessarily, but you will need to manage them appropriately and get managed copies from the EntityManager before making changes.